# Is it possible to downgrade an LUX encrypted Ubuntu 22.10 to 22.04 LTS

Tags: encryption, displaylink

I want to go back to LTS version of Ubuntu for display driver an personal reasons on my lenovo thinkpad that has an LUX encrypted HDD. However. Booting with an Ubuntu installation USB. I can't select or see the current installed version.

Do I need to wipe and redo my entire installation somehow?

Comment: It is not possible to "downgrade" Ubuntu installations in a safe way.  The only option here is a full system reinstallation.  If the disk is encrypted, you would need to backup any data you want to keep to external media while booted into your current system, and once your backup is done erase and reinstall from scratch a new Ubuntu 22.04 installation then restore your data yourself.

Comment: LUX? or did you mean LUKS?  I have re-installed Ubuntu desktop products using some encryption methods, but I'm not familiar with LUX sorry  (*and I've not tried with full disk encryption*)